# Understanding BottomSheet Behavior Collapsed vs Hidden

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a bottom sheet with its height and width set to `match_parent`. So when on button click I set the behavior to `STATE_EXPANDED` like this:

```
mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

My Bottomsheet is defined as below:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="@dimen/design_appbar_elevation"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_content"
            layout="@layout/bottomsheet_layout" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

I am monitoring states with the BottomSheet Callbacks.

- I click on a button and bottom sheet expanded to full screen.
- Its current State is `STATE_EXPANDED`
- I quickly swipe down on the bottom sheet. (Not fully drag till it closed, simple swipe down like scrolling)
- It stops at the middle and its state is logged as `STATE_COLLAPSED`
- If I swipe again it is all gone and its state is `STATE_HIDDEN`

I don't understand why it stops in the middle. How can I make it hidden with a single swipe.

I tried that by setting `peek_height` to `0dp`. By this, it never encounters the `STATE_HIDDEN`. When hidden, its state becomes `STATE_COLLAPSED`. I just don't understand this states.

How to achieve `STATE_HIDDEN` with a single swipe down?

Answer (score 15):

Kinda late but I just stumbled upon this while searching for something similar.

This is how you can skip the collapsed state:

In XML by adding `app:behavior_skipCollapsed="true"` to the BottomSheet view.

**OR**

Programmatically with [setSkipCollapsed(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html#setSkipCollapsed(boolean)).